# Group fcm message from every chat room separately

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, grouping, chat

I have already succeeded to send/receive from/to group fcm

> ***the problem is:***

I need to collect the message coming from the same group together Like Facebook Messenger :
Application Name,then chat room name,then messages from the same room
*

> **Example :** I need instead of the current
>   separated messages in attached photo:

```
Learning ways  <<the name of app
num2           <<room name 
Mon: 6         <<message1
Mon: 7         <<message2
Mon: 8         <<message3
```

**Current Notifications Call:**

```
  @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH)
    private void showOreoNotification() {


        OreoNotification oreoNotification = new OreoNotification(this);
        Notification.Builder builder = oreoNotification.getOreoNotification(title, sender_name + body, pendingIntent,
                defaultSound, icon).setLargeIcon(senderImages);
        oreoNotification.getManager().notify(i, builder.build());
        i++;
    }

  private void showOLdNotifications() {


        assert icon != null;
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(Integer.parseInt(icon))
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(sender_name + body)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSound)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).setLargeIcon(senderImages);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        assert notificationManager != null;
        notificationManager.notify(i, notificationBuilder.build());

        i++;
    }
```

[image: Text]

Answer (score 0):

You can use InboxStyle for Android 4.1+

Message format:

```
val str1:String = "%s : %s".format(sender, message)
```

InboxStyle:

```
Notification notif = new Notification.Builder(mContext)
      .setContentTitle(room_name)
      .setContentText(subject)
      .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
      .setLargeIcon(aBitmap)
      .setStyle(new Notification.InboxStyle()
          .addLine(str1)
          .addLine(str2)
          .setContentTitle("")
          .setSummaryText("+1 more"))
      .build();
```

You can use [MessagingStyle](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html#messaging-style) for Android 7+

```
var notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
        .setStyle(NotificationCompat.MessagingStyle("me")
                .setConversationTitle(room_name)
                .addMessage(message1, timestamp1, null) // Pass in null for you.
                .addMessage(message2, timestamp2, user2)
                .addMessage(message3, timestamp3, user3)
        .build()
```

Comment: thanks so much Kasim, i already solved it by:inbox-style notification using : https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/group   and posted answer ,but someone deleted my answer i don't Know why,but thank you for your help